# locationManager.getBestProvider returns null for API 15 ( API < 23)

Tags: android, gps, kotlin, locationmanager, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have already skimmed through the Android Documentation regarding runtime permissions and still can't find a workaround to make the function below to work for API below 23. Changing the provider to LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER also causes a runtime error (requested provider gps doesn't exisit). I have also set the targetSDKVersion to 15 and still no avail.

functions (requestPermission is triggered onCreate)

```
fun getUserLocation(){
    var myLocation = MyLocationListener()
    var locationManager=getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    val criteria = Criteria()
    criteria.accuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
    var provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true)

    if(provider !=null) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10, 3f, myLocation)
        lblAddress.text=location!!.latitude.toString()
    }

}
private fun requestPermission(){

   if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
     ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }


   }
    getUserLocation()
}
```

build.gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
   defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.appName.appName"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
   }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'


   }
```

Comment: Could you please post logcat and manifest

Comment: @7geeky Nothing shows up in the logcat. Also I have already included the following at the manifest     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />